# Gerrit Change Canonical URL

Tags: .htaccess, gerrit

I have set up gerrit on my subdomain at gerrit.mydomain.com. By default gerrit is running on port 8080 so i have changed the port in gerrit.config [httpd] section to 80 so now gerrit.mydomain.com open gerrit home page.

Now when i print canonical url by running following command:

```
git config -f ~/gerrit_folder/etc/gerrit.config gerrit.canonicalWebUrl
```

It still shows url as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

And its the problem now when i sign in by openID it returns to my domain as gerrit.mydomain.com:8080 and nothing happens because there is no server there

Can you please tell me how can i fix this so that it redirects to gerrit.mydomain.com and canonical url will be changed to `http://localhost:80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gerrit.canonicalWebUrl` is not related to the `httpd.port` configuration. This makes sense if you use a proxy server (such as nginx or apache) where you forward port 80 or 443 (webserver) to port 8080 (gerrit)

You have to edit your gerrit.config and adjust the canonicalWebUrl line to the hostname it should be.
You should able to run `git config -f ~/gerrit_folder/etc/gerrit.config --add gerrit.canonicalWebUrl "http://gerrit.mydomain.com/"`

I also highly recommend using a reverse proxy with ssl.